# Angular js application is not loading after using ['ui.grid']

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am new to angular js. I have downloaded ui-grid.js and ui-grid.css to implement ng-grid in our existing angular js project. I have added the path for both of them in Index.html like below.

```
<link href="app/assets/vendor/css/ui-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="app/assets/vendor/scripts/ui-grid.js"></script>
```

But when I try to use it in tPController.js file like below, the page is not loading, application itself is not coming up.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('dApp',['ui.grid']).controller('tPController', function ($timeout, $scope) {
        var vm = this,
---------------
});
})();
```

Note that i have not yet started using ng-grid in the html file. Only using ['ui.grid'] in .js file is causing the issue.

Comment: Are you by loading angular before ui-grid? Like so;
````<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/release/ui-grid.min.js"></script>````

Comment: yes
<script src="app/assets/vendor/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/assets/vendor/scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/assets/vendor/scripts/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="app/assets/vendor/scripts/ui-grid.min.js"></script>